# Only Displaying one row Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want this data to display all the results, in the query I get 129 results. But when I display it on the page I only get one row.  I have used very similar code to get multiple results before, so I know it`s something simple, but I just can't get it. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT SUM(datamb) AS value_sum FROM maindata GROUP BY phonenumber";
$sql1 = "select dataplan as currentplan from maindata GROUP BY phonenumber";
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT phonenumber AS value_sum1 FROM maindata";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

$result1 = mysql_query($sql2);
if (!$result1) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql1) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
if (!$result2) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql2) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<TABLE id='display'>";
echo "<td><b>Data Usage This Period: ". ROUND ($row["value_sum"],2) . "MB</b></td> ";
}
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
       echo "<TABLE id='display'>";
   echo "<td><b>Data Plan: ". $row1["currentplan"] . "</b></td> ";  
}
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){    
   echo "<TABLE id='display'>";
   echo "<td><b>Phone Number: ". $row2["value_sum1"] . "</b></td> ";    
}
?>
```

Updated based on suggestions - Very helpful thank you, I am very close, all values are correct but I can not get them in the same table, thoughts?

Comment: are these quotes actually in your code?

Comment: You have a lot of parse error in this code :( Can You fix it

Comment: There's obviously inconsistent code-blocks. There's `{ ... }` without `if` `while` or `foreach` starters.

Comment: add semicolon after each of these `$db_username = " 
$db_pass = "
$db_name = "`

Comment: Have you tried this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY To use ,
     Loop in you code eg.

```
   $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT phonenumber AS value_sum1 FROM maindata");

 echo '<table>';
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<th>id</th>';
 echo '</tr>';

 while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
 echo '<tr>';
 foreach ($record as $val)
{
   echo '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
}
 echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
"LIMIT 0, 1" at the end of query
```

or

edit query like "select TOP 1 from....."

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it easy on you ;)

have a look here how to use mysql_fetch_assoc

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

follow the examples, you will be done in a sec.

Comment: This was actually very helpful!